# high charts parse json data

Tags: php, json, highcharts

Silliest doubt possible unable to fix it..:( 
I'm trying to echo a result like below need to separate each date with comma, but to the last date(element) i am getting an extra comma.. how to fix this issue.. Please help

[[Date.UTC(2012,01,26),17],[Date.UTC(2012,01,27),14],]

My code to echo

```
echo "[";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {      
   echo "[Date.UTC(".$row ['date']."),".$row['frequency']."],";
      }
 echo "]";
```

Due to this error I'm unable to parse the json data to highcharts.. 
my high charts code..Please let me know am i going wrong in highcharts..

```
  <script> 
  var chart;
   $(document).ready(function () {
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container1',
        type: 'area'
          },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'double',
        min: 0
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %y', this.value);
            },
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {

                month: '%b \'%y',
                year: '%Y'
            }
        }
        },
       series: [{
        name: 'Total Views',
        data: []
        }, ]

      });

     chart.series[0].setData(

   });
   </script>

  <script>    
   $.getJSON('data.php', function(data) 
   {
  chart.series[0].append(data);
         }   

    </script>


 <div id="container1" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to solution to do this.
first one is to remove the latest "," with substr.
the second is to do this

```
echo "[";
$result = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{      
   $result[] = "[Date.UTC(".$row ['date']."),".$row['frequency']."]";
}
echo implode(',', $result);
echo "]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't embed the `,` in the string you're building. Build an array of strings, then implode it:

```
$data = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
   $data[] = "[Date.UTC({$row['date']}),{$row['frequency']}]";
}

$string = implode(',', $data);
```

Tada, no extra `,`.